# JMeter: adding extra characters in the payload \r\n

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

Here is the JsonPayload that I am trying to post using Jmeter

```
 {
       "myProperties": {
          "sample1": "sample2",
          "sample3": "sample${myVariable}"
     }
     }
```

Before posting, i am generating a random variable and storing it in myVariable.

I see from Jmeter that the request is created like this when posted:  and I am expecting it to work

```
{
   "myProperties": {
      "sample1": "sample2",
      "sample3": "sample234"
 }
 }
```

But when checked in the server logs it is being sent as:

```
{\r\n
   "myProperties": {\r\n
      "sample1": "sample2",\r\n
      "sample3": "sample234"\r\n
 }\r\n
 }
```

If I post the raw request(like below) - It works fine. Only when I introduce the variable it fails. Can somebody please help?

```
{
       "myProperties": {
          "sample1": "sample2",
          "sample3": "sample234"
     }
     }
```

Comment: \r\n are just new line in windows, does it failing or just ignoring it?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

`payload = "{\r\n \"name\": \"xyz\",\r\n \"amount\":
\"9000\",\r\n \"userId\": \"60\"\r\n}"`

Maybe It will helpful for you.